# CSS - media query not working

Tags: html, css

I am trying to hide a div on desktop but show it on mobile i.e. the div will be visible on mobile only. The code is [here](http://dabblet.com/gist/11313086)

I want this portion of code

```
         <div class="mobiupdbox">
         <div class="ovalmain"> Updates</div>
         </div>
```

to be executed only in the mobile version.But it shows up on desktop version too.

Interestingly enough when I uploaded the same code on jsfiddle [here](http://jsfiddle.net/kd86z/) it is working as per expected (i.e. the 'Updates' section is not showing). I just cannot understand where am I going wrong.Please help me guys.I have been trying to sort this one for quite some time now.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you just want to hide the div at sizes greater than 600px - then in your media query
use :

```
@media all and (min-width: 601px) {.....}
```